# Generate an Integer in the range [1, N] without rand() or truncating functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, soft-question, random

I am working in a platform that does not support more advanced math functions such as trig functions, modulus, ceiling, floor or rand(). I have access to [+, -, *, /]. Is it possible to create an expression that can find a "random" integer from 1 to N starting from a seed integer value (such as time in seconds). The value does not technically need to be random but non-repeating and non-sequential.

From what experimenting and searching I have done I don't expect that an elegant solution exists and that this approach for "random" selection should be abandoned. Maybe some clever thinkers here have some ideas for this problem?

Comment: Is the division floating point division or integer division?

Comment: You can implement modular arithmetic with your basic operations.

Comment: @Karl: An even simpler way is to take advantage of unsigned integer overflow, which produces results modulo $2^n$ where $n$ is the number of bits in an integer.

Comment: @Jesse: What is this function *for*?  Generating unique identifiers?

Comment: Maybe [xorshift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift) suits your purpose and platform.

Comment: I am using Trello (web application) and wanted to select random items from a list but my only method for accessing items is by text matching. So I number each checklist item in the text such as "N) <insert text>" and address it with a wildcard like "<random number>) *". This is where the problem originated but the goal now for me is to just understand if its possible to produce semi random integers with basic operations.

@Karl How would you implement modular arithmetic with basic operations? I was searching for specifically this at one point but did not find much information.

Comment: Did you see egglog's question? Do you have recursion or looping?

Comment: My understanding is that it uses floating point division.     

There is a form of "for each" looping for prefabricated lists but I have not seen a way to create a formula or use an existing function that would allow recursion.